# Cocos2dx can be used in android studio development with java?

Tags: android-studio, cocos2d-x

I downloaded the cocos3.14.1 in  the cocos2dx official website, and then use the online method to create a project structure, and then compiled out android
Studio version of "proj.android-studio", and finally with the android studio to the success of this project can also be run. But then how do I develop it? Map, event, interface, logic how to write?
After importing there will be an activty inheritance Cocos2dxActivity, and a package "org.cocos2dx.lib". But I do not know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write most of the game logic in C++ and keep your class files in "Classes" directory.

You would have to update the android project include these C++ files.

If you're using a mac, it is easier to develop it in Xcode, and build it for android in the last step. That way you can debug all the game logic in Xcode and simulator quickly.

In the project that is initially created, your game logic starts in the AppDelegate file (by setting things like the design resolution etc), and the first scene is the "HelloWorld" scene.

Since you're new to this, why not just purchase a book and get started, or read any of the many tutorials available online.

Comment: That is to say that I have to play the game inside the cocos creator, android studio is just a tool for packaging and debugging?

Comment: no - you can play the game on android studios emulator, or Xcode's emulator, on visual studios emulator, or even a real device!

Comment: You can write the code in android studio also - its just more tedious than Xcode or VS because you have to compile the native code from there command line if you use android studio.. android studio is better just for the java parts...